# How to make my scrollbar on local component actually work?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to create an alarm app, but I struggle with css, I want the div containing the list of alarms to be scrollable, firstly the entire screen had a scrollbar which I didn't want, then I managed to restrict the size of the ul containing the alarm list to its parent's size, and now I want to be able to scroll locally to the ul, but I can't, even with overflow-y: scroll
Here is the React component containing everything:

```js
const App = () => {
  /* some react code */
  return selectedAlarm ? (
    <AlarmEditor
      {...{
        selectedAlarm,
        addAlarm,
        setAlarm,
        removeAlarm,
        exitEditor,
      }}
    />
  ) : (
    <div className="main">
      <div className="clock">{time.format("HH:mm:ss")}</div>
      <div className="alarms">
        <div className="alarms-title">
          <h1>Alarms</h1>
          <button onClick={async () => setSelectedAlarm("new")}>
            Add Alarm
          </button>
        </div>
        <ul className="alarm-list">
          {alarms.map((alarm) => (
            <li key={alarm.id} className="alarm">
              <div onClick={() => setSelectedAlarm(alarm)}>
                {alarm.time.format("YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm")}
              </div>
              <button onClick={() => removeAlarm(alarm.id)}>Remove</button>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

and here is the CSS related to it:

```css
.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}

.clock {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: gray;
}

.alarms {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.alarms-title {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 4fr 1fr;
}

.alarm-list {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}

.alarm {
  height: 100px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 4fr 1fr;
}
```

I want to be able to scroll on the ul with the alarm-list class name